# Python file not opening [FileNotFoundError:]

Tags: python, file

I want to create a log file with the current date included in the name of the file and then send data to the log file.

```
import time

current_date = str(time.strftime("%d/%m"))

data = 'test data'

log = open(current_date+"log.txt","a")
log.write("> "+data+"\n")
log.close()
```

When run, this results in the following error:

```
'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '09/04log.txt'
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Don't use `/` in your filename. `09/04log.txt` is the file `04log.txt` in directory `09`, which probably doesn't exist. Just change your date format.

Comment: By the way `time.strftime` already returns a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of backslash in `current_date`
The result will be `a/b` which tells python that `a` is a directory and `b` is file so the end result will be `01/01log.txt` which refers to `01log.txt` file under `01` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the file if it doesn't exist. Also, file names can't contain forward slashes, so you're trying to open from a directory that likely doesn't exist.

Name the file better and use `a+` mode

Comment: I tried this already, Still an [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '09/04log.txt'

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you are trying to create a file in a non-existing directory, and that is forbidden. You should create the folder first:

```
try:
  os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(current_date))
except OSError as e:
  if e.errno == 17:
    # directory already exists
    pass
  else:
    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

## If you want to create a new folder with the file in it:

The folder must exist beforehand when using `open()`.

```
import time,os

def foo():
    try:
        current_date = str(time.strftime("%d/%m"))
        data = 'test data'
        log = open(current_date+"log.txt","w")
        log.write("> "+data+"\n")
        log.close()
    except FileNotFoundError: # If there is no folder...
        os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(current_date))
        foo()
```

## If you just want to use `/` in a filename

That isn't allowed, you can't do that. Other symbols you cannot use are:

- `\`
- `|`
- `*`
- `?`
- `"`
- `<`
- `>`

---

Even if you try to name a file manually with one of these characters, and you'll notice that you can't:

[image]

In this case it isn't allowed because it's like saying "append this to the .txt file in this folder". And there is no folder, you can't do it.

---

<sup>***Side note***: I would be using the `with` statement, and also use `current_date = time.strftime("%d/%m")` as it is always a string</sup>